# Passing Object Parameter To Main Function Java

Tags: java, arguments, program-entry-point

I have objects that look like this:

```
{id:1,name:john,age:15},{id:2,name:david,age:40}....
```

And I want to pass them to my java program as arguments and keep the connection between them.
If I could do something like that:

```
public static void main(Object[] args){
}
```

It could solve my problem but I can't so I thought about this solution:
Argument one:"1,2"
Argument two:"john,david"
Argument three:"15,40"
Then, split each Arg by ','
And keep the relationship between them by the place in the array
I don't like this solution.
Do you know better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static void main method is the starting point of every java application.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

if you modify that signature, the application never find a start point to be executed...

the most you can do is pass a string

the signature can not be modified to this

```
public static void main(Object[] args){
}
```

it must be always

```
public static void main(String[] args){
}
```

so you still have one shot, put this:

> {id:1,name:john,age:15},{id:2,name:david,age:40}

in a text File and pass the Path as string to the app so it can be found

Comment: Or, pass  the `String` to `main` and parse it. If it is large, the file is a better idea.

Comment: What do you define as "large"? 300 objects its large or it's better to pass as string?

Comment: It will be only 3 parametrs. But each parameter will be very long(will hold 300 values)

Comment: Put the values in a file, and then pass the file name as a parameter for it to read the values from. You could also use a JSON parser and put them in JSON format if that is easier for you.